# XNA Simulate trial mode not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone, trial

For some reason the simulate trial mode function in XNA is throwing no errors but having absolutely no efect whatsoever.

I call it in the constructor like this:

```
        public Game1()
        {
#if DEBUG
            Guide.SimulateTrialMode = true;
            Debug.WriteLine("Set trial mode");
#endif
...
```

I then try reading it from the initialize function like this sothat I can eventually tell it to create an addvertising component or not:

```
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Is trial: " + Guide.IsTrialMode);
    ...
```

In my debug console I then get this strange message that the block of code in DEBUG did indeed run but that for some reason tiral mode is not being simulated. Here are the two significant lines:

```
Set trial mode
Is trial: False
```

Do any of you have any idea what could possibly be causing this,thanks.

PS. This is a Windows Phone 7 XNA project.

EDIT:

ALSO, even though it is a WP 7 project is is intended to be able to run on Wp 7 and WP 8. I have also now noticed that it DOES WORK on the WP 7 emulator but not the WP 8 emulator that I was testing it on. Is this a problem only with the simulation on WP 8 and will it work once it is on the store with real licenses or is it a problem with the entire licensing system?

Comment: What is the code for `Guide.SimulateTrialMode`? Is it a property or a field?

Comment: What is called first, the `Game1` constructor or the `Initialize` method? Are they in the same class?

Comment: Ok, so this does work in some cases on emulators. But have you tried running it on a real wp7/wp8 devices?

Comment: Yes I have run it on a real wp8 device and it behaves the same as on the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a know bug in WP8 emulator, SimulateTrialMode just doesn't work.
For debugging you should implement your own wrapper for getting the IsTrial value and define in manually in code or using build configurations.